# Rails 3.0 Action Mailer Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering what is the line of code that comes before the following:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
:user_name            => '<username>',
:password             => '<password>',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

I know in rails 2.3 it's something like this:

```
 Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
```

Is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3, you can do something like this:

config/environments/development.rb or config/environments/production.rb

```
YourApplicationName::Application.configure do

    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
       :port                 => 587,
       :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
       :user_name            => '<username>',
       :password             => '<password>',
       :authentication       => 'plain',
       :enable_starttls_auto => true  

    }

end
```

where YourApplicationName is the name of the application specified while creating the rails app.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out. Also, do you know what the domain is for? Does it need to be specified? In addition, in rails 2.3 authentication was 'login.' Is there a difference between plain?

Comment: Sorry, do you also know what enable_starttls_auto is for?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Well the answer provided did not work. So I toyed with it and this is the code that worked:

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "mail.somesite.com",
   :port                 => 26,
   :domain               => 'somesite.com',
   :user_name            => 'no-reply+somesite.com',
   :password             => '123',
   :authentication       => 'login',
   :enable_starttls_auto => false

}
```